# mobile programming

Tags: android, java-me

Im trying to find an idea for my third year project related to mobile programming with Android or J2ME. anybody has any new idea of mobile application? or at least something that is worth to work on it for the third year project?

Comment: They let you choose between Android and J2ME? I'm having a hard time finding a good reason for a *student* to choose J2ME over Android.

Comment: they dont mind any of them. what do you mean??? which one do you suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Stack Android client, of course!

Someone is working on an iPhone version already:

https://stackapps.com/questions/623/six-to-eight-an-iphone-client

**Edit**: Answered too quickly: there's an Android app too. The good news is that the source code is available, so you can learn from it!

https://stackapps.com/questions/585/droidstack-for-android

Answer (score 5):

application that listens to loud music, and classifies as what genre is.

More useful if done for ballroom dances: waltz, tango, cha-cha-cha, rock'n'roll, jive, foxtrot, slowfox, rumba etc. It would be awesome to have an app that tells what kind is this music, and how to dance to. This will enhance your dance knowledge too. It would be awesome.

Comment: Yup, and I'd like to have some electric muscle stimulation on top so I don't have to do the dancing myself, that'd be awesome. No more awkward situations at marriages.

Answer (score 2):

A VIM keyboard for Android. Given that Android has no mouse a keyboard that would allow as much as possible of the VIM shortcuts would be awesome.

The project would have the potential to be used by a lot of programmers who want a decent editor and therefore would look good on a CV.

Answer (score 1):

a Formula 1 Live Timing application, that is missed from Market

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to get involved in the Hecl project, there are lots of interesting things you can do with it:

http://www.hecl.org

The Android port could certainly use some hacking.

Answer (score 1):

A Location aware application that find the location using GPS and Celltower lookup.

Answer (score 0):

a better WYSIWYG/GUI builder for Android like droiddraw.org was

Comment: That's not a Mobile Application, that's a Web app :p

Answer (score 0):

A gas consumption tracker for cars. Some already exist, but they have loads of bugs inside...

Answer (score 0):

Pick one of your hobbies or interests, and ask yourself what could an app on a mobile phone do to help you do that thing better.  Better to pick something that you are interested in and willing to spend time learning how to do the programming, than getting stuck with a mindless "interesting" problem suggested by someone else.

Basically, pick a technological itch and scratch it!  Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

make an application that allows user to take tests and quizzes and to extend it make applications that allows user to make tests of their own..

you can have questions and answers read from phone memory card or from res folder